# DirectoryInfo.Create fails for remote drive

Tags: c#, windows

I have the following C# code running in a windows service.

```
var downloadDir = new DirectoryInfo(fullPath);
if (!downloadDir.Exists)
{
        downloadDir.Create();
}
```

The code works when it fullpath is on the local machine
however if it is remote the code fails on the .Create line with the error

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
```

Even though at the dos command window the machine does have access to the path

The service is running under the local system account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception message states, the application is not authorized to access the path.

1. Make sure that the path is shared.
2. Make sure that the service credentials (Log On As) has access to the path. Usually you would create a dedicated network account for this or if you have a domain account that can access the said path. Configure this on the service properties on Services.msc or on your installer inside the project.

Comment: I was able to configure it using the logon tab inside services.